# How to filter UID which has request and response in log file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gawk

I want to find out the unique uids from a log file which have request and response.

Each UID is linked with request and response, if the requests gets completed successfully the reponse will come with same uid as with request.

The log file format is as follows. This log has other irrelevant lines too but each uid should have request and reponse, I need those uids only

```
2013-04-03 10:51:01,808 INFO [Logger]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><amp;lt;UID&amp;gt;073104c-4e-4ce-bda-694344ee62&amp;lt;/UID&amp;gt;&amp;lt><begin request>

2013-04-03 10:51:02,898 INFO [Logger]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>amp;lt;UID&amp;gt;073104c-4e-4ce-bda-694344ee62&amp;lt;/UID&amp;gt;&amp;lt>complete reponse>
```

output required in below format

```
UID reponsetime(milisecond)( end time - start time)

073104c-4e-4ce-bda-694344ee62 1090
```

Comment: I agree, here is what I am doing, FIrst I am taking all uids which has request in log file then I'm taking those uids and greping on response . Is ther any quicker way to do it. When I try in bash it takes around 30 min for 2 millions records.

Comment: You already got answers in your original question, can't you tweak one of those?